# How to pass arguments to functions that pass those arguments to other functions used as argument

Tags: ocaml

I know the title is absolutely confusing but maybe this description will make it clear

I am writing a function that applies the same function to the result of itself

```
let add1 x = x + 1

let twice f x = (f (f x))
```

Now I want to write `add2` using `add1` and `twice`, so I do this

```
let add2 = twice add1

let%test "Testing add2..." =
  Int.(=) 1337 (add2 1335)
```

and the test pass, but then I thought since we are passing the int value with `add2` maybe another argument should be there in the function signature of `add2` and be passed to `add1`

so I wrote this

```
let add2 x = twice add1 x
```

and this also passes the test, which is the correct way to do it and why does this happen?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-conversion, https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct and they both mean the same.
A third—and equivalent—way of writing your example is:

```ml
let add2 = fun x -> twice add1 x
```

ocaml is a functional programming language, and as such it allows you to return a function as a result of another function.
Let's consider

```ml
let add x y = x + y
```

`add` has the type `int -> int -> int` which is actually `int -> (int -> int)` that is a function taking an integer as argument, and returning a function on integers.
You can thus write `add1` as follows:

```ml
let add1 = add 1
```

We applied `add` of type `int -> (int -> int)` to `1 : int` so `add 1` has type `int -> int` and corresponds to the function taking `x` and returning `1 + x`.
When you apply `add` to two arguments `x` and `y`—namely `add x y`—you are actually writing
`(add x) y`.

In the end you manipulate functions and the function `f` is the function which associates `f x` to `x` or in other words `fun x -> f x`.

(I hope this is not too confusing.)